# Best method to edit content?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, updates

I have a page which contains a UL -
what I'd like to do is be able to delete a Li element or add a Li element via jquery / php / what you think best.

The user would need to be able to name the li class, specify an image and add a few words description.

Whats the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Well that depends on whether the user has to log in first, in which case PHP would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery:

you can append new elements with:

```
$("#myUl").append($("<li>New List Item</li>"));
```

or remove them:

```
$("#myLi").remove();
```

to add a class you can:

```
$("<li>New List Item</li>").addClass("New Class");
```

to add a text:

```
 $("<li>New List Item</li>").html("New Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Rich text editor that gives a WYSIWYG view.

TinyMCE is a good free one.

Alternatively, a form and a couple of input boxes, then a bit of Javascript can add a new LI to your UL via jquery or direct DOM manipulation.

However, do you need these additions to be saved to some kind of storage ?

Comment: the changes would need to be saved to the webpage, i guess like a mini cms style?

Comment: Basically yes.  It's not necessarily hard, but it really does depend on what you're using as a back end ... is this just a normal HTML file or is it something that's generated ?  if it's not generated then there's no simple way to store changes. If it is, then you just need to make your editor part of a html form, or use JQuery's ajax methods to post the new LI contents.

Comment: itsjsut HTML hence i was hoping i wouldnt need to change it to php etc for link reasons..

Comment: I'm afraid it's not going to work like that, as soon as you need to give people the ability to add content, you need to start looking a generated content. That said, the internet wouldn't work as it currently does if it wasn't possible to keep hyperlinks the same in generated content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full WYSIWYG editor like [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

If you don't want to go that far, you need to develop a Content Management System yourself with PHP and Javascript.

It wouldn't take too long but you might need to create a login system which would mean storing user details in a database.  It's a steep learning curve if you haven't done it before.  How much experience do you have?

Comment: I do have some experience if it was me id just updatye it manually but i have a user wh owants to be able to add or remove li elements from the page at any given time.

Comment: Ok, well I'd use JQuery then. `$("#li-id").hide()` and `$("#li-id").show()`

Comment: No, you'd have to have a database which you add the li entries to using PHP and then use PHP again to query the database and display each one wrapped in li tags.  If you want more help on that, I can post a full solution.